# Django Rest Framework API Authentication Test

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm writing tests to check if the Authenticated users have access to the API Endpoints.

On my test settings, I have set the defaults for Rest Framework Authentication and Permissions Classes. The default setting is that everyone has to be authenticated to access the API.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
)}
```

This is the function which is failing (and all others). Here, I create a user object with a custom UserFactory which is setting a default email and password for each user created. Then I use the APIClient with basic authentication to log in. I'm following the official [Django Rest Framework Documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#authenticating)

```
def test_retrieve(self):
    user = UserFactory.create()
    client = APIClient()
    client.login(email=user.email, password=user.password)
    entity = AttributeChoiceFactory.create()
    response = self.get(retrieve=entity.pk)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    item = json.loads(response.content)
    self.assertEqual(type(item), dict)
    self.assertEqual(item['pk'], entity.pk)
    self.assertItemsEqual(AttributeChoiceSerializer.Meta.fields, item.keys())
```

The test fails with Not Authorized Status Code `AssertionError: 401 != 200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies on this line: `response = self.get(retrieve=entity.pk)`

Since you are using `client` to login, you must continue to use it to send requests: `response = client.get(retrieve=entity.pk)`